# i have one component which is present in all other components , and i want to go back to previous page from where i came from, what is the way?

Tags: react-native

Notification component

which is present in the Home component, History Order Component, Profile Component,

when I clicked the notification icon, from the home page, I go to the notification page,

presuppose I clicked the notification icon from the profile page, and go to the notification page, but when I navigate to go back, I am going to the home page, instead of going back to the profile page

Comment: Are you aware if the `history` is being stored somewhere? So, if user navigates from `Profile` to `Navigation` then the `history` will track the the previous page was `Profile`.

Comment: Welcome, please add your codes with your clarifications, what you tried and what issues you are facing now.